# csv file causing Dygraph to throw Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') error

Tags: javascript, python, csv, dygraphs

I'm using dygraph to show data from various sqlite3 databases and because I don't know better, I am using Python to create a csv file from the database, which dygraph then uses. Using the exact same python code for a different database, the graph displays fine, but with this database in question (that stores data from a solar panel charge controller) I get the above "undefined" error. Googling implies this is because a certain variable is not declared when the dygraph script runs. The same JS that I am using works with a different csv file, so I can only assume its the csv file or the database. I've tested the csv file in Excel & Google Docs and it loads and looks fine visually.

So, any ideas?

Here is the Chrome console error message when the chart tries to load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Q.visibility (dygraph.min.js:4:26567)
    at Q.getPropertiesForSeries (dygraph.min.js:4:889)
    at o.generateLegendHTML (dygraph.min.js:5:13732)
    at o.deselect (dygraph.min.js:5:13159)
    at Q.cascadeEvents_ (dygraph.min.js:3:25191)
    at Q.clearSelection (dygraph.min.js:4:10470)
    at Q.mouseOut_ (dygraph.min.js:4:10406)
    at mouseOutHandler_ (dygraph.min.js:3:30272)
```

Here is the HTML / JS used to display the Dygraph (nrg_chart is a place holder to show a second chart once I get the first one working):

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" />
</head><body>
<div class="container" style="display: flex; height: 350px;">
    <div id="solar_chart" style="width: 50%; height:350px;">
    </div>
    <div id="nrg_chart" style="flex-grow: 1; height:350px;">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  solchart = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById('solar_chart'),
    "solarpwr.csv", {
      title: ['Solar Generation'],
      visibility: [true],
      axes: {
        x: {
        },
        y: {
          drawGrid: false
        }
      }
    });
</script>
</body></html>
```

And then for reference this is my terrible python code I am using to create the csv file, but this works with another database, so I don't think this is the issue:

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/restapi/database.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select battery_percentage, load_current, load_power, pv_current, pv_power, date from solarnrg;")
with open('/var/www/html/solarpwr.csv', 'w',newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    csv_writer.writerows(cursor)
conn.close()

csv_data = pd.read_csv('/var/www/html/solarpwr.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
col = csv_data.pop("date")
csv_data.insert(0, col.name, col)
csv_data.to_csv('/var/www/html/solarpwr.csv', index = False)
```

And if you want to take a look at the database and csv files, here they are: [Gofile links](https://gofile.io/d/DIvskp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`visibility` option](https://dygraphs.com/options.html#visibility) is an array of booleans, one boolean for each data series. Your CSV file has five series (six columns) but the `visibility` array only has one, which is why you're getting the error.

```js
solchart = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById('solar_chart'),
  "solarpwr.csv", {
    title: 'Solar Generation',
    visibility: [true, false, false, false, false],
    axes: {
      x: {
      },
      y: {
        drawGrid: false
      }
    }
  });
```

(The [`title` option](https://dygraphs.com/options.html#title) is supposed to be a string, not an array, but this seems to work OK.)

Comment: You wonderful person. That was it, so obvious come to think of it. Thank you very much indeed ;)